# mp4 video file not prompting for save in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mp4

On my web application on clicking a link, a video file of mp4 file format gets downloaded.
It works fine in all browsers except IE.

In all other browsers, on clicking the link first of all a prompt appears, which ask for whether to save the file or open the file.

But in IE, on clicking the link, the prompt never appears, and on top of that the file starts playing automatically.

How to resolve the issue, so that in IE too, the prompt starts appearing and working properly.

Also is there any sort of java script function to resolve the issue.